# Does order matter when using spread syntax in React component?

Tags: reactjs, performance, tslint, spread-syntax

We are using spread operator in react component using {...Input} which also have onChange method, then our custom onChange need to wrote before spread or after the spread operator?

Does order matters while we use spread operator.? does method overriding is being done here?

Means which is  correct and valid and preferred way to write, In terms of performance and syntax.

```
<Input type='text' {...input} onChange={onChange} />
```

Or

```
<Input type='text' onChange={onChange} {... input} />
```

Sorry to mixing 2 3 questions together, please do not tag it as unapproved or vote to closed. Now a days asking questions in SO going difficult. lol

I am also looking for general practice of to write spread item either on first place or last place in React Component , any lint rule?

Comment: I'd do onChange after spreading input because if input also has an onChange property then that will override the onChange you just put on.

Comment: Yes it matters & any thing after {... input} can override what input has

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it does matter.

```
<Input type='text' {...input} onChange={onChange} />
```

in this case the "onChange" method inside "input" will be overwritten by the "onChange" outside of it. and in the other case visa versa.

I think depending on which one do you want to overwrite you can bring it inside input like:

```
input = {...input, onChange}
Or
input = {onChange, ...input}

<Input type='text' {...input}  />
```

Answer (score 3):

> {...Input} which also have onChange method

Then order matters. The later one overwrites the previous one.

> which is correct and valid and preferred way to write, In terms
>   of performance and syntax.

There is no performance differences. Order depends on your needs. If you want to overwrite `onChange` use this:

```
<Input type='text' onChange={onChange} {... input} />
```

Comment: I think ur example and your statement are contradictory. I want to overwrite my custom function over spread item function then I think we need to write custom function after {...Input}

Comment: @diEcho I assumed you want to overwrite the `onChange` function in `<Input>`. If you want to overwrite the one inside the prop, put it first. The one comes last, overwrites the previous one.

Comment: I want to overwrite < Input /> 's onChange method with my own onChange so obviouly need to write after {... input}. Why would I overwrite my own function?

Comment: @diEcho My example overwrites < Input /> 's onChange method. What is the contradiction then?

Comment: Your code in answer does not overwrite input 's onChange but do it reverse. .